# Jackson: deserialize an Object that was serialized with findTypedValueSerializer()

Tags: jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

In my JsonSerializer I have this code:

```
// Variable needs to be of type Object
Object object = new Person("John Doe");
...
JsonSerializer<Object> serializer = serializers.findTypedValueSerializer(object.getClass(), true, null);
serializer.serialize(object, generator, serializers);
```

Which nicely serializes to this JSON:

```
{"@class":"org.foo.Person","name":"John Doe"}
```

because my class is annotated like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public class Person {
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

**How do I deserialize that JSON text with my `JsonDeserializer`?**

---

**Null Pointer Exception** is thrown by this code:

```
JsonDeserializer<Object> deserializer = context.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(context.constructType(Object.class));
TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer = context.getFactory().findTypeDeserializer(context.getConfig(), context.constructType(Object.class));
Object object = deserializer.deserializeWithType(parser, context, typeDeserializer);
```

Comment: Please add complete exception details. Also you want a generic deserialization where you are not aware of what class should be used for Deserialization? When you use `Person` class directly?

Comment: In the real code, I writing optaplanner-jackson integration and the Person class is an example of a user class that isn't in optaplanner, nor jackson, so it's unknown at compilation time, but a Person instance might end up in the Object field of an optaplanner class that needs to be serialized/deserialized.